# Is there a way to return a pandas dataframe with a modified column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `df` with column `"age"`.
Say `"age"` has some `NaN` values and I want to create two new dataframes, `dfMean` and `dfMedian`, which fill in the `NaN` values differently.
This is the way I would do it:

```
# Step 1:
dfMean = df
dfMean["age"].fillna(df["age"].mean(),inplace=True)
# Step 2:
dfMedian= df
dfMedian["age"].fillna(df["age"].median(),inplace=True)
```

I'm curious whether there's a way to do each of these steps in one line instead of two, by returning the modified dataframe without needing to copy the original. But I haven't been able to find anything so far. Thanks, and let me know if I can clarify or if you have a better title in mind for the question :)

Comment: Here `dfMean`, `dfMedian`, and `df` are all the same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `dfMean = dfMean["age"].fillna(df["age"].mean())` you create a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`.

To add two new `Series` (=columns) to your `DataFrame`, use:

```
df2 = df.assign(age_fill_mean=df["age"].fillna(df["age"].mean()),
                age_fill_median=df["age"].fillna(df["age"].median()),
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You alternatively can use alias [`Pandas.DataFrame.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

*"Aggregate using one or more operations over the specified axis."*

```py
df.agg({'age' : ['mean', 'median']})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, need 2 times defined new 2 DataFrames by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with dictionary for specify columns names for replacement missing values:

```
dfMean = df.fillna({'age': df["age"].mean()})
dfMedian = df.fillna({'age': df["age"].median()})
```

One line is:

```
dfMean,dfMedian=df.fillna({'age': df["age"].mean()}), df.fillna({'age': df["age"].median()})
```